A triple summation problem: $\sum_{i=1}^{100} \sum_{j=i}^{100} \sum_{k=i}^{j} 1$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{100} \sum_{j=i}^{100} \sum_{k=i}^{j} 1&= \sum_{i=1}^{100} \sum_{j=i}^{100} (j-i+1)\\&= \sum_{i=1}^{100} \left(\sum_{j=i}^{100} j - i \sum_{j=i}^{100} 1 + \sum_{j=i}^{100} 1\right)\\&= \sum_{i=1}^{100} (5050 - 100i + 100)\\&= \sum_{i=1}^{100} (5150 - 100i)\\&= 5150 \sum_{i=1}^{100} 1 - 100 \sum_{i=1}^{100} i\\&= 515000 - 505000\\&= 10000\end{align}$$
I think the answer should be $171700$, but I can't figure out where I made a mistake
Note: Today I came across a computer science problem that requires this calculation, and, just a few hours ago, I had no idea how to do a double summation.
So yeah, your help would be needed.

In third equation you are expanding $\sum_{j=1}^{100}$ inside brackets instead of $\sum_{j=i}^{100}$

$\sum_{j = i}^{100} j \neq 5050$.

Hint
$$\sum_{j=i}^{100} j=i+(i+1)+...100\\=\frac{100×101}{2} -\frac{(i-1)i}{2}$$
